# How to create action hotspot in UI document

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got some nice little LotusScript that I can put into the Click event of an Action Hotspot in a rich text field when I'm sending an email manually. Is there a way to programmatically create that in the UI?

My script determines the user's home server and then opens a specific document in the replica of a training database on their home server. I could create these messages with hotspots manually and provide them to the folks who want to email them out. Of course, time being money and the task being boring, I'd rather automate it. I know that I could do this by using a stored form, but am wondering if the greater capability exists, as I can see further applications for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick I used in the past was to create a profile document in a database, and store some rich text in a field on that profile doc.  Then when I needed to programmatically send an email, I could get that rich text field from the profile doc and use AppendRTItem to get it into the body of an email.  That should work with any type of rich text, including hotspots.

Note: this won't work in the UI to populate a new email. It does work if you are generating the emails completely in code, though.

Comment: I've used the same trick in code that runs on the server, but I've not tried it in code running in the UI.

Comment: @Richard Schwartz,I meant that same trick but I don't think that was clear from my original answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In the UI, you could use the undocumented action:
    call NotesUIDocument.ImportItem(NotesDocument, NotesRichTextItem)
Note that it only works in R8.5+ (As far as I remember), and inserts an unwanted carriage return in R8.5.2 which does not occur in R8.5.3.
Of course, as it's undocumented, take care as it may not last forever.  It's used in the mailfile template, so I reckon it'll be around for a while though :-)